# Which automation tool suits for hydraulic machines automation

Tags: automation

I want to make a  machine for coconut tree maintanence, comprising of 
        1. Hydraulic/knumatic lift
        2. Electrical cutting machine
        3. Small pressing pliers
        4. Remote controlling system
Process: 
    Note:   Consider all the above mentioned units are attached on top of the lift.

> Lifting the lift and start cutting the coconut leafs
>    Applying pressure in some part of the tree's head
>   I plan to do these entire process through automation. I need some ideas about automation tools/products suit for this automation.
>    I am good in java and similar programming concepts. I have some knowledg on plc/aurdiono by browsing.
>   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any PLC or PC based control. Since you have Java knowledge you can try "PLC Open" controllers with ST (Structured Text) programming language.
Beckhoff TwinCAT 3 has a good implementation for that matter. TwinCAT 3 is OOP language, but is more similar to C++ than to Java. It also connects to every EtherCAT enabled device. Keep in mind that it will probably be more expensive then cheap stand-alone PLC supporting only Ladder Diagram and own hardware.
EtherCAT (remote) I/O will operate same on top of lift as near the controller (PC).

To design the device you described you will need suitable hardware and 
electrical components as I/O units, contactors, valves, sensors, etc...

Safety is very important when you have heavy moving parts and hydraulic pressure. Beckhoff TwinCAT 3 has safety module but it is only programmed as functional diagram. Per my experience safety should be the first thing in mind.